# How to write one line bash if with background executing command

Tags: bash

I need an one line if statement

```
if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then do-something &; fi
```

I want to put task `do-something` to background with `do-something &`, but bash complains

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I then tried to escape `&` with `\&`

```
if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then do-something \&; fi
```

But it seems not right, the task rans in foreground, not background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the `bash` manpage:

> A  simple command is a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and terminated by a control operator.

And a control operator is defined as a:

> ... token that performs a control function. It is one of the following symbols: `||`, `&`, `&&`, `;`, `;;`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `|&`, `<newline>`.

So, `&` is *itself* a control operator and you are only allowed *one* those at the end of a simple command. Trying to execute something like:

```
sleep 10 & ; echo now
```

will give you the same error as:

```
sleep 10 ; ; echo now
```

The correct way would be:

```
sleep 10 & echo now
```

---

In terms of what that means for you, the correct way to do it is without the dual control operator:

```
if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then do-something & fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the final semi-colon. Try `if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then do-something & fi`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Up voted! I decided to accept paxdiablo's answer because it gave future reader a complete picture.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval`.

```
if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then eval "do-something &" ; fi
```

This will execute your `do-something` in background.